# Converting a line to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this line of Javascript which runs a function I sourced online. However it turns out to not be ie compatible so I'm looking to convert it to a Jquery call.

I have absolutely no Jquery experience and while the documentation is good, I need a hand understanding how to get it to gel with pre-existing Javascipt.

```
classElements[i] = document.getElementsByClassName(show_hide_class_selectors[i]);
```

I have found the class selector at http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ which seems to do what I want.

If I used this line (show_hide_class_selectors[i] is a string)

```
classElements[i] = $("." + show_hide_class_selectors[i]);
```

Will classElements[i] then contain all nodes of the class provided by show_hide_class_selectors[i]?

I'm asking now so I don't spend the next 2 hours downloading, messing and then getting pissed with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `$(".foo")` will return all nodes having the class `foo`, but wrapped in a jQuery object.

If you just want a plain array of DOM elements, you'll need to do `$(".foo").get()`.

Comment: classElements[i] = $(".foo").get(); works but classElements[i] = $("." + someVariable).get(); doesn't in ie.

Comment: @YsoL8: Then there is something else wrong in your code. I'm pretty sure string concatenation also works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.className')
```

That will return a list of all elements with class of "className". Also:

```
$('.className').show()
$('.className').hide()
$('.className').toggle()
```

Will show all those elements // hide them // and toggle between.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
classElements[i] = [];
$("." + show_hide_class_selectors[i]).each(function(index) {
    classElements[i].push(this);
});
```

After this, `classElements[i]` will contain all elements having the class defined in `show_hide_class_selectors` array - same result as in your non cross browser code.